# Berkeley Pac-Man Project: features divided through by 10

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am busy coding reinforcement learning agents for the game Pac-Man and came across Berkeley's CS course's Pac-Man Projects, specifically the [reinforcement learning section](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/pacman/projects/reinforcement/reinforcement.html).

For the approximate Q-learning agent, feature approximation is used. A simple extractor is implemented in [this code](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/pacman/projects/reinforcement/docs/featureExtractors.html). What I am curious about is why, before the features are returned, they are scaled down by 10? By running the solution without the factor of 10 you can notice that Pac-Man does significantly worse, but why?

Answer (score 0):

After running multiple tests it turns out that the optimal Q-value can diverge wildly away. In fact, the features can all become negative, even the one which would usually incline PacMan to eat pills. So he just stands there and eventually tries to run from ghosts but never tries to finish a level.

I speculate that this happens when he loses in training, that the negative reward is propagated through the system and since the potential number of ghosts can be greater than one, this has a heavy bearing on the weights, causing everything to become very negative and the system can't "recover" from this.

I confirmed this by adjusting the feature extractor to only scale the `#-of-ghosts-one-step-away` feature and then PacMan manages to get a much better result

In retrospect this question is now more mathsy and might fit better on another stackexchange.